# Multiple DIV overlays on a single page

Tags: jquery

This code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".one").hover(
        function(){
            $(".overlay").fadeTo(200,1).show();
        },
        function(){
            $(".overlay").delay(500).fadeTo(200,0);
        }
    ); 
});
```

overlays a second DIV on top of the first, but breaks for multiple instances on the same page. I think I need to put a `$(this)`. in there somewhere but can't figure out where.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The HTML code help, and a JSFiddle is even better.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you provide a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I'll do a JSFiddle but the site doesn't seem to be loading up fast, if at all.

Comment: jsFiddle was apparently suffering from heavy traffic even before SO users started to ask every questioner in the `[jquery]` tag to use it. Maybe we should stop doing that.

Comment: Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/vDBRk/

Comment: How does it "break"? For multiple instances of .one or multiple instances of .overlay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access it by traversal. Assuming it is a child of the element 'one', this will only apply the effect to children named 'overlay' of the hovered element 'one'.

```
$(".one").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).children(".overlay").fadeTo(200,1).show();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).children(".overlay").delay(500).fadeTo(200,0);
    }
);
```

Heres a reference of [jQuery tree traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Comment: If you add .stop(true, true) before the animation, it will prevent a possible endless chain of hover start/stops as well, here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/73Y8x/

Comment: Interestingly that removes the delay effect. But I guess the quicker transition eliminates, as you said, that chain of animations.

Comment: Ah yes, an oversight, simply change round .stop and .delay - updated http://jsfiddle.net/73Y8x/1/

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you did need a `this`:

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".one").hover(
        function(){
            $(".overlay",this).fadeTo(200,1).show();
        },
        function(){
            $(".overlay",this).delay(500).fadeTo(200,0);
        }
    );
});
```

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zZYT/)** (with the heights reduced for easy viewing).

The way "this" works here is that when you hover over the .one div, "this" refers to the div you're hovering over. The functions inside the hover event will refer to the div being hovered over and do whatever you want to do to them. Without the "this" the actions you apply in your functions would get applied to all the elements with the class "overlay" and not just the overlay within the div being hovered over. "this" in effect limits the actions being applied based on the element being hovered over ("this"). In other words, `$(".overlay",this)` qualifies the context and restricts it.

Comment: I guess with experience I'll get used to the variation in how the "this" part is implemented. I was trying to drop $(this) in somewhere. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've added a brief explanation about his this works in the context of my example.